# How can I share database connection between packages in Go?

Tags: database, go

I declare my database connection in my `main` package, sort of like this:

```
package main

var Db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "stuff...")

    // error handling and more app stuff
}
```

To begin with I had all of my code in the `main` package and I could access the database connection from other files. However, I want to separate code into packages, and now the `Db` variable isn't visible anymore.

Is it possible to share it across packages or do I have to add it as a parameter to whatever calls to other packages I have in my `main` function?

Comment: Either export the variable from some package (e.g. `DBConn` or somesuch) or pass it into the sub-packages as required. Just like you'd do with any other piece of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll share a bit of code currently in one of my apps.

First...

```
package conf

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func ConnectDB() *gorm.DB {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", /**/)
    if err!=nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.LogMode(true)

    return &db
}
```

Then....

```
package model

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

func SetDatabase(db *gorm.DB) {
    DB = db
    // Some other set up here
}
```

Finally...

```
package main

import (
    "conf"
    "model"
)

func main() {
    db := conf.ConnectDB()
    model.SetDatabase(db)
    // Some other stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even though this answer works perfectly fine, I ended up using [this approach](https://elithrar.github.io/article/custom-handlers-avoiding-globals/) which is http-oriented and suits my application better (and doesn't use globals at all).

Comment: Much better approach.